# How to load custom post type field values in Wordpress from the database?

Tags: database, wordpress, custom-post-type

I was reading this [link](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/events-listing-custom-post-types-wordpress/) about creating a custom post type in Wordpress. In the example, the field value box is text and the user can enter anything inside. I was wondering if it's possible to turn that field value box to a dropdown one, which values are loaded from the database. So for example, under 'Date', there is a dropdown box next to it with dates loaded from the database. Anyone know if it's possible? Thanks!

Comment: yes it is possible to grab data from a database and put it in a dropdown box. you can create one using [add_meta_box](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box) and then use [$wpdb](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) to get items from the database.

Comment: @DavidChase is correct that this is more of a suggestion than an answer, but I have used Advanced Custom Fields in the past to easily and quickly customize input screens for custom post types: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/